# Check if all variables in a dataframe are used in calculations in same script

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that consists of a lot of variables that nearly all should be used in calculations. How can I check, if the variables "VarX" are actually used in the same script (section: #Calcs to #Calcs End) and if they are not used print them out? Imagine the script looks like the following:

```
df1<-data.frame(Diff_Var_other=c("A","B","C","D"),
                Var1=c(1,2,3,4),
                Var2=c(2,3,4,5),
                Var3=c(3,4,5,6),
                Var4=c(4,5,6,7),
                Var5=c(5,6,7,8))

#Calcs

df1$test_var1<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var1","Var2")])
df1$test_var2<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var4","Var5")])

#Calcs End
```

I wanted to use an if-clause combined with a stop code and as a following of the stop code print out the unused variables but do not know how to make it happen.

Comment: How can you not know if you are going to use your variables?  If you wrote the code, you know.  If not, wrap the code in a function and define the arguments properly and it will become apparent very quickly if something is missing (or extra).

Comment: In this case, you may benefit from providing a more specific/complex example of what you're working with - or at least more details in your current example (ie, what columns should be in `test_var1` and `test_var2`?). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

```r
## Unused variables
df1<-data.frame(Diff_Var_other=c("A","B","C","D"),
                Var1=c(1,2,3,4),
                Var2=c(2,3,4,5),
                Var3=c(3,4,5,6),
                Var4=c(4,5,6,7),
                Var5=c(5,6,7,8),
                Var6=c(5,6,7,8))

calc_rowmeans <- function(df1) {
  df1$test_var1<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var1","Var2")])
  df1$test_var2<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var4","Var5")])
  return(df1)
}

unused_vars <- list()
try(for (i in grep("^Var\\d+", names(df1), value = TRUE)) {
  df <- df1
  df[i] <- NULL
  possibleError <- tryCatch(
    calc_rowmeans(df),
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if (!inherits(possibleError, "error")) {
    unused_vars[[i]] <- i
  }
}, silent = TRUE)

if(length(unused_vars) > 0) {
  print(paste("Variable in dataframe not used in function:", unused_vars))
  stop("Verify input data")
} else {
  df2 <- calc_rowmeans(df1)
  df2
}
#> [1] "Variable in dataframe not used in function: Var3"
#> [2] "Variable in dataframe not used in function: Var6"
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Verify input data
```

```r
## No unused variables
df1<-data.frame(Diff_Var_other=c("A","B","C","D"),
                Var1=c(1,2,3,4),
                Var2=c(2,3,4,5),
                Var4=c(4,5,6,7),
                Var5=c(5,6,7,8))

calc_rowmeans <- function(df1) {
  df1$test_var1<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var1","Var2")])
  df1$test_var2<-rowMeans(df1[,c("Var4","Var5")])
  return(df1)
}

unused_vars <- list()
try(for (i in grep("^Var\\d+", names(df1), value = TRUE)) {
  df <- df1
  df[i] <- NULL
  possibleError <- tryCatch(
    calc_rowmeans(df),
    error = function(e) e
  )
  if (!inherits(possibleError, "error")) {
    unused_vars[[i]] <- i
  }
}, silent = TRUE)

if(length(unused_vars) > 0) {
  print(paste("Variable in dataframe not used in function:", unused_vars))
  stop("Verify input data")
} else {
  df2 <- calc_rowmeans(df1)
  df2
}
#>   Diff_Var_other Var1 Var2 Var4 Var5 test_var1 test_var2
#> 1              A    1    2    4    5       1.5       4.5
#> 2              B    2    3    5    6       2.5       5.5
#> 3              C    3    4    6    7       3.5       6.5
#> 4              D    4    5    7    8       4.5       7.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks jared! I like where this is going, however I probably made an error by oversimplifying my example data.frame. There are also variables like Diff_var_other "behind" Var5. And i would also like the error only to occur if one of the Variables Var1 to Var5 is missing in the "Calc-section" + only print names from those Variables.

Comment: Hopefully my edited answer will work for your use-case @Christioh; otherwise I think you'll need to edit your question to provide more details